# Neo4J Cypher Shell won't use curly brackets in any way

Tags: windows, neo4j, keyboard, cypher-shell

I  tried everything, switching keyboards, using virtual keyboard, copy and paste, but the shell won't in any way, on windows 10, display or recognize curly bracket. I don't know why. I tried to see if there were shortcuts that could interfere but nothing. Other symbols seem to work!